# Catch response from Koa.js for testing

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, koa

I'm using Mocha for my TDD Tests.  I want to be able to check that a route is returning at least something, a response, and that's it but not sure what type is being sent back by a Koa GET route under the hood...like I know it returns a response over the wire to the user but what is the TYPE I can test for straight up in my tests when trying to hit that router.get with koa-router...

any idea how I can tell what that returns?

Answer (score 0):

```
app.use(route.get('/', list));
app.use(route.get('/goods/:id', getinfo));
function *list(){
    this.body = 'hello';  //return front info
}
function *getinfo(id){
    this.body = 'The ID is'+id;
}
```

Comment: So this is based on a non-running (there is no app.listen at this point) app right? Just need an app instance but I do not want it listening on a port because unit tests are not integration tests and running my test logic against a running app (app.listen) would not what I want. As long as I can just test the app instance and not app.listen then this is what I am looking for. I assume this is how you were thinking as well...app instance here right?  Because my test needs to test in isolation, not on an app.listen so if I can just do it with app, that'll work like you show.  I'd wanna mock too